# I sound like a newb, but is CKeditor supposed to be installed onto the root of EE so Wygwam can actually work?

Tags: wygwam, ckeditor

ok so this sounds basic;

1. I've installed latest wygwam 3.3.3 and seemed to install fine.
2. ok so is CKeditor supposed to be installed onto EE on the root? Because between CKeditor's lack of answers for installation with EE and wygwam's lack of explaining how CKeditor is installed with its product, I'm lost.
3. any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything but install Wygwam. CKeditor is just installed under Wygwam, you can find it in

```
themes > third_party > wygwam > lib > ckeditor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the addon correctly, you do not need to do *anything* with CKeditor.

Make sure you've copied these folders:

```
Wygwam3.3.3/themes/third_party
-> copy to 
your-web-root/themes/third_party

Wygwam3.3.3/ee2/third_party/
-> copy to 
your-web-root/system/expressionengine/third_party
```

and then make sure you install the addon through the Add-ons -> Modules page in the back end. IF you're looking to use CKeditor separately from EE, you can find the copy that comes with Wygwam in this folder (from the installation folder):

```
Wygwam3.3.3/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor
```

But it might be a modified fork of CKeditor (probably is) for use with Wygwam, so if you need to use it separatly, I would recommend downloading it separately.